# Does the `index` option on Rails column migrations work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-migrations

I can write a migration like:

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :bar, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) `index: true` should also create an index for the table on that column however I can see in `schema.rb` that it does not.

Is this a known bug or is it related to my setup? FWIW I'm on Rails 4.1.8 using Postgres and PostGIS.

This also doesn't work for the longer syntax of `t.column :bar, :string, index: true` though it does seem to work for `t.belongs_to`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it only works with numbers, because indices are for speeding up association retrievals.

Comment: Your exact code works for me in Rails 4.2, `db/schema.rb` ends up with: `add_index "foos", ["bar"], name: "index_foos_on_bar"` in it.

Comment: You're right though, it doesn't work in 4.1.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, confirmed, this does not work as advertised in 4.1.8 nor in 4.1.9, and yes, it's a bug.

The bug is fixed in 4.2.0 (and the 4.1 -> 4.2 upgrade is simple).

Comment: Thanks for doing that digging!